# Partial views with unique IDs

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, partial-views

I'm using partial views in a loop and this is generating multiple id="item_itemD" inputs (I'm using Html.HiddenFor to generate the input).

What can I do to use partials so my markup can be html 4.01 strict?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could pass in an integer value to the partial and append that to the ID before incrimenting for the next itteration.

```
var counter = 0;
foreach(var item in items)
{
  Html.RenderPartial("MyPartial",counter);
counter ++
}
```

If you're already passing a model to your partial view, you might consider creating a basic view model contining your current object and the int as properties.

```
Html.RenderPartial("MyPartial", new MyViewModel{Counter = counter; Model = item}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer Jamie! I'm not actually using the ID so isn't there a different way that just doesn't generate the ID? I'm thinking of not using the hiddenfor helper at all and just write the input bit by "hand".

Comment: I think you can just specify an empty Id attribute in the htmlAttributes property of the HiddenField. Somethingl like Html.HiddenFor(m => m.bla, new {@id = ""});

Comment: that's it, thanks! =) When the id is empty the id doesn't even appear. I suppose the model binding is using the name (item.itemid) so maybe I can keep using model binding.

Comment: The model binder is using the name yeah. Glad it's working for you Arthur. :)